# How to dismiss keyboard on UISearchBar touchesBegan in swift 4

Tags: ios, swift

I have searched items in table view using UISearchBarDelegate.
I have set search bar variable's delegate to self like so

```
searchBar.delegate = self
```

touchesBegan function I have used to hide keyboard.

```
  override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>,
                           with event: UIEvent?) {
    self.view.endEditing(true)
}
```

When i touch any where other than search bar, it doesn't get triggered. Although same thing is working fine with UITextField.

Comment: Maybe try searchBar.endEditing(true)

Comment: This touchesBegan function doesn't get triggered, no matter what do I write inside.

Comment: Weird. Did you add any gesture or tap recognizer?

Comment: When I touch anywhere on table, table cell getting selected. May be this is the issue? I don't have any other space where I can touch.

Comment: See my updated answer. Should work ;)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe try:

```
searchBar.endEditing(true)
```

or even better:

```
searchBar.resignFirstResponder()
```

**Edit:**

Now that you explained what your issue is, here's what you can do:

```
func searchBarTextDidBeginEditing(sender: UISearchBar) {
     self.tableView.userInteractionEnabled=false
}
```

And then just reenable on searchBarTextDidEndEditing.

Otherwise what you could do is actually adding the gesture recognizer to the tableView as such:

```
let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(dismissKeyboard))
tableView.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)
```

Answer (score 0):

> (BOOL)searchBarShouldBeginEditing:(UISearchBar *)searchBar This delegate method will help you to perform the above task.

```
- (BOOL)searchBarShouldBeginEditing:(UISearchBar *)searchBar{
      return NO; // return NO to not become first responder
      }
```